# Mount additional water bottle on bike frame with only one water bottle mount

Tags: hydration

I only have one set of water bottle mount screws on my bike.  I would like to have an additional water bottle.  Ideally I would like to mount the bottle on the frame (preferably on the vertical tube).

*Bonus: Can I order/build in Canada?*

Comment: It's quite easy to strap an extra mount to a round tube.  But many bikes these days have odd-shaped tubes and the strap-on mounts won't work very well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Twofish Quick Cage](http://www.twofish.biz/bike.html) has worked well for me. Not terribly pricey, and easy to reposition as needed. Not as secure as the hose clamp solution, however.

Answer (score 8):

Get yourself two hose clamps that'll fit around the tube and some rubber strips to put under then so they don't scratch the paint up too badly. They'll hold a bottle cage on just fine.

If you can see under the dirt and grime, that's exactly how the bottle cage in this picture is mounted:

[image]

Edit: Here's another picture of a bottle cage mounted with hose clamps (not mine). 
[image]

Comment: I'll give you +1 if you clean off all that grime and take a picture that lets us see the details...  =)

Comment: And once upon a time you could buy (cheap) clamps at bike shops specifically designed to do this.  I used a set on my first touring bike.

Comment: I know for a fact that hose clamps are available in Canada.

Comment: @darkcanuck - That'd be tough, since the bike is in a landfill now. But [this picture](http://www.flickr.com/photos/cavenewt/3211631293/) is *slightly* clearer, and if you click through to my picture, I've added notes to show where the hose clamps are.

Comment: I bought a bike that came with no(!) cages, nor any place to put them(!!), but hose clamps like this solved the problem handily.  If the bike shop doesn't have them, you can buy them at a hardware store.

Comment: Most bikes I've run across don't have water bottle mounts built in.  It's just the brand-new and older, but very expensive for the time frames that have the mounts.  The hose clamp method is quite common.

Comment: Just going to say, when buying the hose clamps, make sure you can fully unscrew them if you're planning to put them on the inside frame. Nothing worse than getting some, going home, and finding out they're designed so they can't open up and won't go on.

Answer (score 4):

Are you only considering a frame mount? If not, there are options for mounting a cage on the [seat rails](http://www.nordicgroup.us/cageboss/#Seat_Rail_Mount_with_Integrated_Cages), [seat post](http://www.nordicgroup.us/cageboss/#Seat_Post_Mount_), and [handlebars](http://www.nordicgroup.us/cageboss/#Clamps_for_Handlebars_Only). In addition, if the frame is all that you'll consider, there are a number of options for ["clamp-type" water bottle systems](http://www.nordicgroup.us/cageboss/#Clamps_for_Frame,_Seatpost,_or_Long_Steer_Tubes_%28on_Folders%29_).

You didn't mention, but if you have a carbon frame you'll need to choose an appropriate clamp so as not to damage the frame.

Not sure if you use a seat bag? An option is to switch from a seat bag to a dual-mount seat-rail water bottle cage; and then, carry your extras in something like this, [http://www.amazon.com/Tacx-Tool-Tube-Storage-Bottle/dp/B002SR0JRM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002SR0JRM) and if you're frugal, a water bottle could be cut-down for the purpose.

Answer (score 3):

I know this isn't what you asked, but have you considered a [Camelbak](http://www.camelbak.com/Sports-Recreation/Packs/2011-Charge-450.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

I've been facing the same issue, trying to mount an additional bottle cage to the underside of the downtube on my mountain bike.  I haven't settled on one particular solution yet, but I found this site helpful as it outlines various different solutions: http://www.nordicgroup.us/cageboss/

Comment: That page has a seriously exhaustive collection of options. I'm impressed by that alone.

Comment: Aha - the Minoura Extra Cage clamps (or some facsimile) is what I used:  http://www.nordicgroup.us/cageboss/#6._Minoura_Extra_Cage_Clamp-Band_Set

Comment: Good site but it seems like it is not possible to get many of the products listed on the site.

Answer (score 2):

As a Strida owner, I've struggled with exactly this problem. I went with the KLICKFix solution, and couldn't be more pleased.

It's not always I like to carry a bottle, so I really like the fact that I just remove the whole thing in a split second.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to fit additional threaddd mounts to your frame.  This works fine if your frame is **steel**, but I wouldn't try this on a carbon or aluminium frame.

The threaded insert is called a rivnut or a nutsert and looks like this:

[image]

You would drill two holes in your steel frame barely big enough for the OD of your nuts, press the nuts into place, and then use a rivnut tool or a suitably-threaded nut and bolt to crush the rivet part closed.  The thread is  5 x 0.8mm and is the same as your normal water bottle mount bolts, and coincidentally many wheel skewers too.

Epoxy or JB Weld would be a good idea too to help stabilise the insert.

You can also hire rivnut tools from hire companies - they're not cheap.

Answer (score 1):

On a carbon frame I used cheap **Zefal Gizmo** mounts for attaching kit the way it was intended.

[image: mount parts]

Below you can see it carrying a Kryptonite Modulus lock on my bike but you can obviously attach a bottle cage or whatever and wherever you like. I did 100s of miles with it without any issue.

I'm not sure if the mounts came with rubber strips as you can see on the picture. I may have used some spare ones from cycle light mounts for extra grip and protection. You could cut out such strips from an old tube.

[image]